# How Do I Open Downloads Folder From A Button Click?

Tags: java, android

I want my app to open Files>Downloads from a button click. The follow code is not working. All it's doing is restarting my app. What am I doing wrong?

```
Intent launchDownloadsFolder = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri getDLFolder = Uri.parse("file://" + 
DownloadPromptPopUp.downloadDirectory);
launchDownloadsFolder.setDataAndType(getDLFolder, "videos/*");
launchDownloadsFolder.getData();
startActivity(launchDownloadsFolder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can try below code to get the work done.

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Hope this will help you.